# How to understand the interface Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

I know that the implementation of the interface **Serializable** makes an object to be serialized, but how is possible that when the interface is simply a definition of a class with their methods like:

```
interface Serializable {
   public one();
   public two();
}

public class Dog implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ...
}
```

(class Dog doesn't implement any method of Serializable)

Simply I don't understand, can you explain me?

Comment: Serializable is a marker interface.  Try a google search for "marker interface".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the interface has no method...

**Why not?**

because the interface is defined as a 'marker interface'.

**What is that??:**

the interface is used only to TAG objects so that the JVM can get more information about them at runtime

if you have the chance, take a look at the ***Effective java*** from Joshua Bloch:

Quote:

> A *marker interface* is an interface that contains no method
>   declarations, but merely designates (or “marks”) a class that
>   implements the interface as having some property.
>
> For example,
>   consider the Serializable interface (Chapter 11). By implementing this
>   interface, a class indicates that its instances can be written to an
>   ObjectOutputStream (or “serialized”)....

Comment: great, really I'm very glad with your answer!

Comment: To be precise, the JVM plays little or no part in this. *Other classes* do that, such as `ObjectOutputStream`.